# Python's getattr equivalent in my javascript code?

Tags: javascript, python

I'm following a article that was in python and I'm trying to implement the same thing but in javascript, I just don't undestrand the part when he uses `getattr`.
I think it's something like `node.constructor.name`, but I'm not sure because I don't understand how he can call `visitor(node)`.

```
class NodeVisitor(object):
    def visit(self, node):
        method_name = 'visit_' + type(node).__name__
        visitor = getattr(self, method_name, self.generic_visit)
        return visitor(node)

    def generic_visit(self, node):
        raise Exception('No visit_{} method'.format(type(node).__name__))
```

To understand more about it and to see the rest of the code, here is the [article](https://ruslanspivak.com/lsbasi-part7/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getattr` gets an attribute (i.e. `.foo`) from an object, given the attribute name as a string. So `getattr(o, 'foo')` is equivalent to `o.foo`. The third argument is the default value which will be returned if the object does not have that attribute.

The equivalent in Javascript is:

```
o['foo'] || bar
```

You can use any variable for `'foo'` here. If `o` does not have that property, `undefined` is returned (in Python it would raise an `AttributeError`, in Javascript it merely produces `undefined`), at which point the `||` operator would return its second operand instead.

Putting it together, something like:

```
const methodName = `visit_${ node.constructor.name }`;
const visitor = this[methodName] || this.genericVisit;
return visitor.call(this, node)
```

Note that you will have to care about propagating `this` correctly. I'm making a lot of assumptions about your class structure here, but something like this should do.

Comment: perfect assumptions and perfect answer!

Comment: How is work when `o['foo']` is false as boolean (some `0` or `false`)?

UPD. I think you can use `o['foo'] ?? bar`